# How to hide field for normal users and show it for B2B user group in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dropdown, add-on

I still building my first WordPress/WooCommerce site. I'm near to finish the project and looking for a solution to hide a field on the Product Page layout of WooCommerce

I use [Woocommerce Product Add-Ons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/) plugin to display some fields (yellow and Blue cross) on single product pages. You can see that below on this screenshot:

[image: now]

I try to find a solution, that the yellow marked field is only displayed for the user group B2B...

Why is this field there? I try to give "Bulk prices for some Customer's I know there are some plugins for this, but they give only the Discount on the total price... and my goal was to only give the Discount on the "base" Price without any options...

The code located in `select.php` file from the plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying select field.
 *
 * @version 3.0.0
 */

$loop = 0;
$field_name = ! empty( $addon['field_name'] ) ? $addon['field_name'] : '';
$required   = ! empty( $addon['required'] ) ? $addon['required'] : '';
$current_value = isset( $_POST['addon-' . sanitize_title( $field_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( $_POST[ 'addon-' . sanitize_title( $field_name ) ] ) : '';
?>
<p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-<?php echo sanitize_title( $field_name ); ?>">
    <select class="wc-pao-addon-field wc-pao-addon-select" name="addon-<?php echo sanitize_title( $field_name ); ?>" <?php if ( WC_Product_Addons_Helper::is_addon_required( $addon ) ) { echo 'required'; } ?>>

        <?php if ( empty( $required ) ) { ?>
            <option value=""><?php esc_html_e( 'None', 'woocommerce-product-addons' ); ?></option>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <option value=""><?php esc_html_e( 'Select an option...', 'woocommerce-product-addons' ); ?></option>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php foreach ( $addon['options'] as $i => $option ) {
            $loop++;
            $price        = ! empty( $option['price'] ) ? $option['price'] : '';
            $price_prefix = 0 < $price ? '+' : '';
            $price_type   = ! empty( $option['price_type'] ) ? $option['price_type'] : '';
            $price_raw    = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_addons_option_price_raw', $price, $option );
            $label        = ( '0' === $option['label'] ) || ! empty( $option['label'] ) ? $option['label'] : '';

            if ( 'percentage_based' === $price_type ) {
                $price_for_display = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_addons_option_price',
                    $price_raw ? '(' . $price_prefix . $price_raw . '%)' : '',
                    $option,
                    $i,
                    'select'
                );
            } else {
                $price_for_display = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_addons_option_price',
                    $price_raw ? '(' . $price_prefix . wc_price( WC_Product_Addons_Helper::get_product_addon_price_for_display( $price_raw ) ) . ')' : '',
                    $option,
                    $i,
                    'select'
                );
            }

            $price_display = WC_Product_Addons_Helper::get_product_addon_price_for_display( $price_raw );

            if ( 'percentage_based' === $price_type ) {
                $price_display = $price_raw;
            }
            ?>
            <option data-raw-price="<?php echo esc_attr( $price_raw ); ?>" data-price="<?php echo esc_attr( $price_display ); ?>" data-price-type="<?php echo esc_attr( $price_type ); ?>" value="<?php echo sanitize_title( $label ) . '-' . $loop; ?>" data-label="<?php echo esc_attr( wptexturize( $label ) ); ?>"><?php echo wptexturize( $label ) . ' ' . $price_for_display; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>

    </select>
</p>
```

My PHP skills are bad... Maybe somebody sees a solution to add something to my theme's `function.php` file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could see this post from SO: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109337/display-custom-field-for-a-specific-role-but-not-for-admin


I think its pretty much what you need. A conditional to check if the user is X, and if he is, shows the content.